# How to add easing effect on jquery .css function?

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing

How do you add the Jquery easing effects to your jquery script when using .CSS functions?
For example in this other line i made it work, but i can't make it work with .CSS
i am using the [jquery easing library](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

```
$("#map").animate({height:300},1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

And how do i implement it on this .css script?

```
$('#comment-box').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.css` is not animatable, that is what `.animate` is for. That said, I don't think `display` is animatable like that, since it merely toggles between the different display modes. You could use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead.

**Edit:**
Ah, it seems you want `.slideDown()`.

Try this:

```
$('div#comment').slideDown(1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

It is also possible to use `.slideUp()` or `.slideToggle()`.

Comment: Thanks! ill try that out instead! is it still possible to add the easing functionality to the elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it on the element opacity instead of the display attribute.

```
$("#map").css({opacity:0});
$("#map").animate({opacity:1}, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

Though I doubt you will see much of the bounce effect.

Display is an 'on'/'off' type of attribute, no gradation of values is possible. You can get the effect by using opacity like I suggested to do the animation and set the display attribute after animation completion using a callback.

Comment: It's only possible on the .animate function :(?
And yeah , haha thats the whole point. i want the div to "bounce".

Comment: Why not use animate? What's the difference for you between calling css and animate? display is an 'on'/'off' type of attribute, no gradation of values is possible. You can get the effect by using opacity like I suggested to do the animation and set the display attribute after animation completion using a callback.